Awkward Array broadcasting and linear indexing, reshaping an Awkward Array
I'm trying to use numpy-like syntax on an awkward.Array with variable sizes in the second dimension, but it's still confusing..
In numpy i have
normals.shape # (N,3)
idcs.shape    # (m,k)
normals[idcs].shape # (m,k,3)

So the entries of the idcs 2d-array are obviously used as indices for the first dimension of my normals 2d-array and keep that shape.
If I try the same with an awkward.Array, it won't perform that numpy-trick of 'linear-indexing' or 'broadcasting' (whatever you may call it)
# awkward.Arrays here:
normals # N * 3 
idcs    # m * var <- variable sizes in second dimension
normals[idcs] # ERROR
# what I expected instead:
normals[idcs] # m * var * 3

EDIT: what I also thought about, is to reshape idcs to one long index vector, use it to index the normals 2d-array like normals[idcs_vector] and then reshape the result back to m * var * 3 by something like normals[idcs_vector].reshape((m,-1,3)), but since awkward hasn't implemented a reshape function, this is not easy

You might be running into the fact that broadcasting works differently for variable-length dimensions and fixed-length dimensions. (It depends on variable versus fixed type, not whether the number of items happens to be constant.) See https://awkward-array.org/doc/main/user-guide/how-to-math-broadcasting.html and https://awkward-array.org/doc/main/reference/generated/ak.broadcast_arrays.html for "left broadcasting" versus "right broadcasting." With fixed-length dimensions, NumPy could have chosen either method, but with variable dimensions, there's a natural choice (and NumPy's is "wrong").

Reshaping doesn't have a natural definition with variable-length dimensions, either, but what you want to do may be equivalent to ak.flatten followed by ak.unflatten. To get the lengths of lists (second argument of ak.unflatten), there's ak.num.

@JimPivarski I'm aware of left and right broadcasting. I already looked into that, but it didn't really fit my problem, since multiplying entries isn't really what i was looking for.
The ak.flatten and ak.unflatten on the other hand worked for me
